# Implementing a 10 bit shift register with led outputs

Tags: vhdl, shift-register

I am trying to implement the the following shift register

```
entity MyShiftRegister is
    port(
        clock:   in  std_logic;
        DataIn:  in  std_logic_vector (9 downto 0); 
        Left:    in  std_logic;  --synchronous left rotate
        Right:   in  std_logic;  --synchronous right rotate
        Load:    in  std_logic;  --synchronous parallel load
        Clear:   in  std_logic;  -- synchronous clear
        DataOut: out std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
```

This is what I have so far

---

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity question2 is
    Port (
        led: buffer std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
        clk: in std_logic;
        btnu: in std_logic;
        btnL: in std_logic;
        btnR: in std_logic ; 
        btnD: in std_logic;
        btnC: in std_logic 
     );
end question2;

architecture Behavioral of question2 is
    constant active: std_logic :='1';
    constant inactive: std_logic :='0';

    constant step_zero:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000000000";  
    constant step_one:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000000001";
    constant step_two:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000000010"; 
    constant step_three: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000000100";
    constant step_four:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000001000";
    constant step_five:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000010000";
    constant step_six:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0000100000";    
    constant step_seven: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0001000000";
    constant step_eight: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0010000000";
    constant step_nine:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0100000000";
    constant step_ten:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0100000000";

    signal DataIn: std_logic_vector (9 downto 0):= "1111111111";  
    signal Load: std_logic := btnD;
    signal Reset: std_logic; 
    signal Left: std_logic:= btnL;
    signal Right: std_logic:= btnR;
    signal DataOut: std_logic_vector := led (9 downto 0);
    signal Clear: std_logic:= btnU;
    signal speed_enable: std_logic; 
begin
    SpeedControl: process (clk)
        variable counter: integer range 0 to 10000000;
    begin
        speed_enable<=not active;  
        if Reset = Active then
            counter:= 0; 
        elsif (rising_edge (clk)) then 
            counter := counter + 1; 
            if (counter=10000000) then 
                speed_enable<= Active; 
                counter:=0; 
            end if; 
        end if; 
    end process; 

    shiftregister: process(clk, clear)
    begin
        if rising_edge (clk) then 
            if clear= active then 
                DataOut <= (others => '0');  
            elsif load = active then 
                DataOut <= DataIn ; 
            elsif Left = active then 
                DataOut <= DataOut(8 downto 0) & "1" ;
                if DataOut = "1000000000" then 
                    clear <= active;   
                elsif Right = active then 
                    DataOut <= DataOut (9 downto 1) & "1" ;
                    if DataOut = "0000000001" then 
                        clear <= active; 
                    end if; 
                end if; 
            end if; 
        end if;  
end process;

with DataOut select
    led <= step_one   when "0000",
           step_two   when "0001",
           step_three when "0010",
           step_four  when "0011",
           step_five  when "0100",
           step_six   when "0101",
           step_seven when "0110",
           step_eight when "0111",
           step_nine  when "1000", 
           step_ten   when "1001", 
           step_zero  when others;     
end Behavioral;
```

How exactly do I rotate bits left and right and tie that to my led outputs. I was thinking of using a counter and just incrementing and decrementing to shift bits left or right but I'm not sure if that would still be considered a shift register.

thanks

Comment: This code is rife with design errors and makes no sense. Why the mux for `led`? `DataOut` isn't 4 bits; that's a syntax error. Your left shift and right shift branches don't properly shift OR rotate (especially right shift). Your actual entity doesn't match the entity that you provided as what you're trying to implement. The speed control process can't be synthesized because it mixes combinational and registered assignments. Default values (`:=`) are not default CONNECTIONS. Do you understand what a synchronous barrel shifter (described by the `MyShiftRegister` entity) is supposed to do?

Comment: All the other problems you listed I'm still coding for. I just don't understand how to shift left or right without using a counter to move the bits

Comment: `DataOut <= DataOut(8 downto 0) & DataOut(9) ;` ROTATES left, 
`DataOut <= DataOut(8 downto 0) & "0" ;` SHIFTS left,
`DataOut <= DataOut(0) & DataOut(9 downto 1);` ROTATES right, 
`DataOut <= "0" & DataOut(9 downto 1);` SHIFTS right.
 The automatic clearing thing is unnecessary and actually breaks the intended functionality.

Comment: Typically a barrel shifter rotates the bits left or right one position per pulse on the left or right inputs. You're using `DataOut` as your storage element, although it should probably be a differently named signal. The storage element can be copied to your output port something like `led <= DataOut` (in concurrent space, not in your clocked process).

Comment: If I have active high leds. So in order for the leds to rotate do I need to declare any of my DataOut bits initially high

Comment: A barrel shifter with the interface in your template isn't supposed to just rotate a single bit around. It rotates whatever data you loaded into it with a parallel load. The initial state will dictate what LEDs are lit before loading data into it (although this is customarily all 0, all off), but is irrelevant to the later function. Your `question2` entity lacks the parallel data port for you to do the load.

Comment: Quantum Ripple. Thank you so much. I learned more from you through your comments than I learned the whole week on this myself. I am extremely grateful your help. I also found that by making my lsb of Dataout high I it works and shifts the bits correctly. So no I'll just add a clock divider to slow it down and I'm done!!!

Comment: While a clock divider can work, a more usual way to get good performance out of this on a dev board is to run the clock at full speed, but debounce your buttons (DPST switches make this easy with an SR flop, but timers can be used for normal momentary switches) and add an edge detector to create a one-clock wide pulse for your left and right inputs. Load and reset buttons don't cycle through states so they don't need the extra input processing. Low duty cycle clock enables like it looks that your prototype is using is much easier though. Actually dividing the clock comes with other headaches.

Answer (score 1):

To start:

```
constant step_nine:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0100000000";
constant step_ten:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0100000000";
```

is incorrect. It should be

```
constant step_nine:  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="0100000000";
constant step_ten:   std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :="1000000000";
```

But this approach is very error prone anyhow. Lets simplify it:

```
process(sel)
    variable selected_led : natural;
begin
    led <= (others => '0');
    selected_led := to_integer(unsigned(sel));
    if selected_led < led'length then
        led(selected_led) <= '1';
    end if;
end process;
```

If the `led(selected_led) <= '1';` won't synthesize, you probably have to change it to

```
for i in 0 to led'length-1 loop
    if (i = selected_led) then
        led(i) <= '1';
    end if;
end loop;
```

As for using the `buffer` port. Don't. preferably only use `in` or `out`. If you want to read an `out` port, compile with VHDL-2008, or use a temporary signal in between.

Then note that `right` and `left` are keywords in VHDL. you shouldn't use them

What you want is very simple and basic VHDL. Example (using VHDL-2008):

```
process(clock)
begin
    if rising'edge(clock) then
        if clear = '1' then
            data_out <= (others => '0');
        elsif load = '1' then
            data_out <= data_in;
        elsif right_rotate = '1' then
            data_out <= data_out(0) & data_out(data_out'length-1 downto 1);
        elsif left_rotate = '1' then
            data_out <= data_out(data_out'length-2 downto 0) &
                data_out(data_out'length-1);
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```